# raise sa_exc.ArgumentError( sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class car->car could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table

Tags: python, html, turbogears2

I am busy with learning turbogears, which i find a very good and easy to work framework in compare with Django, that gave me many problems with the imports.
i have a .py file which i wrote a code, but doesn't seem to be able to assemble any primary key columns for my mapped table

```
raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper mapped class car->car could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'car'
```

```
from unicodedata import name
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Unicode
from dataproj.model import DeclarativeBase
class car(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'car'
    carid = Column(Integer, Primary_key = True)
    make = Column(Unicode(40), nullable = False, default = '')
    model = Column(Unicode(40), nullable = False, default = '')
    year = Column(Integer, nullable = False, default = '')
    transmission = Column(Unicode(10), nullable = False, default = '')
```

Have tried it with a different format like de sqlalchemy document says but its still not working this is what i typed:

```
from unicodedata import name
from sqlalchemy import PrimaryKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import Integer, Unicode
from dataproj.model import DeclarativeBase

class car(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'car'
    
    Column('car_id', Integer, Primary_key = True)
    Column('make', Unicode(40), nullable = False, default = '')
    Column('model', Unicode(40), nullable = False, default = '')
    Column('year', Integer, nullable = False, default = '')
    Column('transmission', Unicode(10), nullable = False, default = '')
```

and this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/wsgiapp.py", line 82, in __call__
    response = self.wrapped_dispatch(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/errorpage.py", line 64, in __call__
    resp = self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/transaction_manager.py", line 107, in __call__
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/_compat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/transaction_manager.py", line 79, in __call__
    response = self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/caching.py", line 54, in __call__
    return self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/session.py", line 71, in __call__
    response = self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/identity.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/appwrappers/i18n.py", line 71, in __call__
    return self.next_handler(controller, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/wsgiapp.py", line 243, in _dispatch
    return controller(environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/dataproj/dataproj/lib/base.py", line 27, in __call__
    return TGController.__call__(self, environ, context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/controllers/dispatcher.py", line 118, in __call__
    response = self._perform_call(context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/controllers/dispatcher.py", line 107, in _perform_call
    r = self._call(action, params, remainder=remainder, context=context)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/controllers/decoratedcontroller.py", line 129, in _call
    output = controller_caller(context_config, bound_controller_callable, remainder, params)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/controllers/decoration.py", line 21, in _decorated_controller_caller
    return application_controller_caller(tg_config, controller, remainder, params)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tgext/debugbar/sections/timing.py", line 77, in wrapped_controller
    result = profiler.runcall(controller, *args, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/cProfile.py", line 109, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tg/configurator/components/dispatch.py", line 114, in _call_controller
    return controller(*remainder, **params)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/dataproj/dataproj/controllers/root.py", line 127, in showgrid
    data = DBSession.query(car).all()
  File "<string>", line 2, in query
    
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2159, in query
    return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 180, in __init__
    self._set_entities(entities)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 187, in _set_entities
    self._raw_columns = [
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 188, in <listcomp>
    coercions.expect(
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 188, in expect
    resolved = impl._literal_coercion(
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 401, in _literal_coercion
    self._raise_for_expected(element, argname)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 437, in _raise_for_expected
    return super(_SelectIsNotFrom, self)._raise_for_expected(
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 283, in _raise_for_expected
    util.raise_(exc.ArgumentError(msg, code=code), replace_context=err)
  File "/Users/alexandra/TurboGearsProjects/tgenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got <class 'dataproj.model.car.car'>.
```

Comment: can someone help me plzzz

Comment: what i've just done is:     from sqlalchemy import PrimaryKeyConstraint, but still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

In your definition of the `carid` column you have a casing typo - the argument name needs to be all lower case `primary_key=True`.